# Here zoomTo Ignores ViewRect X & Y Positions

Tags: android, here-api

I am attempting to display a route in a map. I am displaying route information over the bottom portion of the map. So I need to offset the route when displaying it. In the iOS SDK I can use the method set:

`func set(boundingBox: NMAGeoBoundingBox, inside: CGRect, animation: NMAMapAnimation)`

The CGRect offsets the route. The Android SDK has a similar method [zoomTo](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/Map.html#zoomTo-com.here.android.mpa.common.GeoBoundingBox-com.here.android.mpa.common.ViewRect-com.here.android.mpa.mapping.Map.Animation-float-)

`zoomTo(GeoBoundingBox var1, ViewRect var2, Map.Animation var3, float var4)`

But it seems to ignore the X and Y starting positions of the ViewRect. It does use the height and width I give it, but the route is always in the center of the screen.

Comment: Can you please provide us some further information about the SDK release- version number and which package (premium or starter)?

Comment: Thanks for getting back with me. I am using the premium SDK v3.11.2. I have also forked the example routing project to make sure it wasn't something in my project. Link is below. I am using 

`ViewRect size = new ViewRect(300, 300, 1000, 1000);
m_map.zoomTo(gbb, size, Map.Animation.NONE, Map.MOVE_PRESERVE_ORIENTATION);`

From my understanding, this should place the route in a 1000 by 1000 box. Offset from the top left corner by 300 pixel. 

https://github.com/jeremiahk/here-android-sdk-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is fixed and it will be available in 3.12 release (planned for beginning of July)

Comment: Thanks for the support